# How to re-run a specific task after its completed using ExecutorService

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool, executorservice

I am trying to create a module that will submit a `Callable` to `ExecutorService` and waiting for response. If the callable returns `null`, this thread will pause itself until `resume()` is called. Or else it will process the result and resubmit same task again.

```
public class ScheduleManager implements Runnable {

    private ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

    @Override
    public synchronized void run() {
        while (true) {
            Future<Schedule> future = executor.submit(new ScheduleRetriever());

            try {
                Schedule schedule = future.get();

                if (schedule == null) {
                    this.wait();
                } else {
                    //Do something with the schedule
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public synchronized void resume() {
        this.notifyAll();
    }
}
```

I managed to come up with above solution but I am not sure if its reliability.

Is there anyway to do this better?

Comment: One question that comes to mind here: why do you submit the `Callable` to a worker thread in the first place when you make the thread that submits the `Callable` block and wait for the worker thread to complete the submitted task? Why not just simply execute the callable directly on the initial thread (i.e., get rid of the worker thread altogether)? Do you do this because you submit these `Callable`s from multiple _different_ threads, yet have a requirement that these `Callable`s are all executed on a _single, specific thread_?

Comment: I made this into `Runnable` because I need to restart the thread if it terminated or encounter some Exception. If I call it from initial thread, the application would terminate if something unexpected happens.

Comment: To me, it sounds like you'd be able to achieve the exact same thing by simply wrapping this code in a try-catch block (re-invoking the code in the catch-block, thereby coping with the failure)?